# Averageif works if i try separately but averageifs gives me an error #DIV/0 though there is data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

It's a simple formula with two conditions.

When i try **=averageif(B:B,"CAT 2,A:A)** or **=averageif(C:C,"Total Loss",A:A)**. It works, but when i try with
**=averageifs(A:A,B:B,"CAT 2",C:C,"Total Loss")** i get an error #DIV/0. I have tried trimming the columns, removing any blanks but still the same error.

What can be the issue here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk3Xm.jpg

Comment: Weird. What does `=averageifs(A:A,B:B,"*CAT 2*",C:C,"*Total Loss*")` return?

Comment: It worked, what these stars do?

Comment: They are wildcards. They match any character(s). Seems like you have trailing or leading spaces or something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding wildcards around your criteria. You may have leading or trailing spaces or some other non-visible character(s) in your data:

```
=averageifs(A:A,B:B,"*CAT 2*",C:C,"*Total Loss*")
```